# Stored procedure selecting items in a category and its descendants

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have these 3 tables

```
Products (Id, Name)
Products_Categories (ProductId, CategoryId)
Categories (Id, ParentCategoryId)
```

As you can see

- `Products` to `Categories` is many-to-many
- A `Category` may or may not have a parent (the parent is also a Category)

How do I create a stored procedure that **selects** all (distinct) **products** under a **category** (including its descendants)

Example pseudocode (not LINQ) of what I want:

```
Category c;
return c.GetSelfAndDescendants().Select(x => x.Products).Distinct();
```

What I need is the stored procedure, eg.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [spAllProductsUnderCateg] 
    @categId int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- This may be completely wrong
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Products p
    JOIN Products_Categories ON Products_Categories.ProductId = p.Id
    WHERE...???
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I was nowhere close before. Added fiddle with functional example**

**Edit2: Updated fiddle for a cleaner procedure and changed code in answer to reflect the correct solution**

This problem requires a recursive procedure to dig down into unknown depths of a tree of descendants. This has potential to be a very expensive operation and as designed here could also lead to an infinite loop if two categories refer to each other as parents, so you may want to incorporate some protection against that.

I used a temp table to collect the results of all the different queries, then returned them with the procedure that calls the recursive procedure, so all that's needed is a call to spAllProductsUnderCateg to return the result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [spAllProductsUnderCateg] 
    @categId int 
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #ProductsByCategory (Name varchar(100))

    -- This may be completely wrong
    INSERT INTO #ProductsByCategory 
      SELECT DISTINCT p.Name FROM Products p
      JOIN Products_Categories pc ON pc.ProductId = p.Id
      WHERE pc.CategoryId = @categId

    EXEC spGetChildCategories @categId

    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #ProductsByCategory

END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [spGetChildCategories]
    @categId int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nextCatId int
    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM Categories
    WHERE ParentCategoryId = @categId

    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @nextCatId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO #ProductsByCategory 
         SELECT DISTINCT p.Name FROM Products p
         JOIN Products_Categories pc ON pc.ProductId = p.Id
         WHERE pc.CategoryId = @nextCatId

         EXEC spGetChildCategories @nextCatId

         FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @nextCatId
      END
    CLOSE cur
    END
GO
```

I'm more experienced in PL/SQL than T-SQL, but this worked in the fiddle. Since it uses recursion, cursors and an extra table you will definitely want to evaluate its performance limitations, but it did work with the data I fed it.

[This is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98d6f/1)

Comment: Hi thanks but it's not that simple. I need to include all products from the category's descendant categories as well. That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Multiple descendant levels would require a recursive procedure, which would call itself to retrieve each level of descendants. I'll have to put together a SQLFiddle to get somewhere with that. I'll see what I can do. My apologies for misunderstanding your requirements.

Comment: Added a link to a fiddle with a functional example.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the fiddle! I think it'll be good if you paste the relevant code here on stackoverflow as well.

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the code on here and tweaked the fiddle a little bit so the procedure returns the result directly using a temp table.